# Code written with some packages gives blank output inside renderPlot function

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny, plotly

The `plot` function of some packages like `timetk`, `plot_ly` does not produce the `plot(output)` written inside `renderPlot` function. Although the same piece of code returns the `output(plot)` when I run it in console. Whereas function like `plot()`, `ggplot()` does the work too.
Why is that so?

This piece of code with timetk library provide the output in rstudio console:

```
dataset %>%
      plot_time_series(.date_var = Year, .value = column1,
                       .interactive = TRUE, .y_lab = "Amt", .x_lab = "Year",
      )
```

But if this same piece is written inside `renderPlot` function, it does not provide the output on RShiny app, just shows a blank white screen.

UI: UI code is all good. I also have written an `plotOutput("p1")` too.

Server:

```
output$p1 <- renderPlot({ 
dataset %>%
      plot_time_series(.date_var = Year, .value = column1,
                       .interactive = TRUE, .y_lab = "Amt", .x_lab = "Year",
      )
})
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Try with `plotly::renderPlotly` and  `plotly::plotlyOutput`.

Comment: @stefan Hey, this was the problem, thanks.

Comment: @stefan Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it and close this post. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is (was) that `renderPlot` and `plotOutput` are meant for base plots or ggplots. As you want to make an interactive `plotly` chart you have to make use of `plotly::renderPlotly` and `plotly::plotlyOutput`.